# How to Show Role Name And Assignedd Permission Name in History Object

Tags: trigger, future

Trigger:

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) { 
    String jsonOldMap = JSON.serialize(Trigger.oldMap);
    String jsonNewMap = JSON.serialize(Trigger.newMap);

    AssignPermissionSetToUserHelper.futureCreateRecord(jsonOldMap,jsonNewMap); 
}
```

This My Helper Class Method:

```
// FUTURE METHOD INSERT RECORD IN 'Permission-set-Assignment-History' OBJECT=== AFTER UPDATE
@future
public static void futureCreateRecord(String stroldMap, String strnewMap) {

    map<id, User> oldMap = (Map<id, User>) JSON.deserialize(stroldMap, map<id, User>.class);
    map<id, User> newMap = (Map<id, User>) JSON.deserialize(strnewMap, map<id, User>.class);

    List<Permission_set_Assignment_History__c> insertPsah = new List<Permission_set_Assignment_History__c> ();


    for(User obj : newMap.values()) {
        System.debug('OBj...'+obj);
        User oldObj = oldMap.get(obj.Id);               
        Permission_set_Assignment_History__c p = new Permission_set_Assignment_History__c ();
        p.Name ='User Permission ' ;//Show AssignePermission Name In History Object
        p.OldRole__c = oldObj.UserRoleid;// how to show role Name 
        P.NewRole__c  =obj.UserRoleid;
        p.UserImpacted__c = obj.Id;// how to show role Name 
        p.Type__c = 'Assigned';
        System.debug('p...'+p);
        insertPsah.add(p);
         System.debug('p..After.'+p);
    }


    if (insertPsah.size() > 0) { 
        Database.insert(insertPsah,false);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi - if you could please add more of a description of what you're trying to accomplish, it would be easier to help you out

Comment: let take a exmple . after update Trigger i want show Old Values And New Values In Custom Object. Like User OldName  And User New Name ,UserRole Name  And Assigned Permission Name

Comment: Iam Calling this Method in @future

Answer (score 0):

You essentially would add queries to get the information. You have all the roles in old and new map. You can loop through them to add them into a list to use the following query to build a map that you can reference to get the name.

```
Map<Id,UserRole> mapRoles = [SELECT Id FROM UserRole WHERE Id in :listOfRoles];
//later on
p.OldRole__c = mapRoles.get(oldObj.UserRoleid).Name; 
P.NewRole__c  =mapRoles.get(obj.UserRoleid).Name;
```

For permission sets, you'd have another query to get that information based on putting all the user record Ids into a list from the trigger maps. The big question is will there be two permission set assignments on the same user at the same time?

```
List<PermissionSetAssignmetn> permNames = [SELECT Id, PermissionSet.Name, ASsigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE AssigneeId in :listOfUsers AND SystemModStamp = lastHour //use some sort of time variable, but remember this is future so it's not guaranteed to happen immediately after. could do this outside the query

Map<Id,List<String>> userPermissionMap = new Map<Id,List<String>>();
for(PermissionSetAssignment psa : permNames){
    for(Id userId :listOfUser){
        if(psa.AssigneeId == userId){
            if(!userPermissionName.containsKey(userId){
                List<String> listNames = new List<String>();
                listNames.add(psa.PermissionSet.Name);
                userPermissionMap.put(userId, listNames);
            } else {
                List<String> existingNames = userPermissionMap.get(userId);
                existingNames.add(psa.PermissionSet.Name);
                userPermissionMap.put(userId, existingNames);
            }
        }          
    } 
}

//appends all the permission set names in one
p.Name = String.join(userPermissionMap.get(obj.Id));
```